# AppStore - iOS, impossible to publish in testflight a new build of the same version

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store, fastlane

I have a problem with fastlane when I publish on TestFlight a new bundle that uses the usual version (ex: 1.0.2):

> Error This bundle is invalid. the value for key
>   CFBundleShortVersionString (1.0.2) in the Info.plist file must contain
>   a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.0.2]

It seems like I need to publish a new version, but I want to publish a new build instead, keeping the same version ... how is that possible?

**Edit Response:**

ok, I understand ... although unlike Android, I don't see the usefulness of blocking a new build if there is the same approved version ... but thank you all!

Comment: With Same Version which is already approved in App Store you can not able to upload new build with same version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to upload new build of the previously approved version. So in this situation you should have to create new version in iTunes Connect and then and then you can able to upload new build in Testflight.

Answer (score 1):

Few cases arise:

1. If you want to keep same version, remove current app from app store and publish your current version.
2. Now there is already app with same version so you cannot allow to do this, either increase the version or go with point 1, how ever be careful with this point. You need to analyse cases, because it is already on appstore.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the same version to TestFlight with increased build number. Eg: 1.0.2(1) and 1.0.2(2) Simply increase the `build` version from Project settings.